# Django and Xcode exception when running website locally

Tags: python, django

I have a functioning Django site, but when I run the website locally, I get the following exception error. It doesn't appear to occur on the hosted site. Nothing I can find is not working, it is just a puzzle to me why this error is coming up and I would like to fix it because it is annoying - but I don't know where to start looking.

Is there a common XCode Django connection that I am overlooking?

```
    ----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 56089)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/u1123114/Documents/projects/kinbank_website/website/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/u1123114/Documents/projects/kinbank_website/website/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: have you tried simply running it from command line? 
 $ python manage.py runserver
Do you get this error?

Comment: Yes, the command line is where this error appears. Sorry that wasn't clear.